# I want to add active at a specific URL using “data-target”

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

However, if other text is added to the URL, active is lost.

Even if other text is added to the url, I would like to keep it active if it contains a specific “data-target”.

For example, if the original link is "link/sub01.html" but changes to "link/sub01.html&page=2", the style is lost.

Even if the text "&page=2" is added, I want active to always be added if "sub01" is in the url.

But I'm not familiar with the script yet, so I don't know where to fix it. Please help me.
I didn't speak English, so I used a translator.

So the sentence may not be smooth. Sorry!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location;
    $('#Nav .Cate li a[href="' + 'data-target' + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('#Nav .Cate li a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.Cate {
    position: relative;
}
 
.Cate li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 34px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
    transition: all .35s;
}

.Cate li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
    transition: all .35s;
}

.Cate li:hover {
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}

.Cate li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.Cate li.active {
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}

.Cate li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Nav">
    <ul class="Cate">
        <li data-target="index"><a href="index.html">MAIN</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub01"><a href="sub01.html">SUB01</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub02"><a href="sub02.html">SUB02</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `return this.href == url;` consider using [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) or [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) ex -`return this.href.startsWith(url)`

Comment: @James Thank you for your comment! The "data-target" values of the links are not constant, so it doesn't work the way you suggested. TT. It may be because I'm not familiar with scripts. But I think I found another way! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a slight change in your code to get the exact `data-target` from the URL and then make the corresponding `<li>` active

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var urlArr = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  var dataTarget = urlArr[urlArr.length - 1];
  $('.Cate li a[href="' + dataTarget + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
  //rest code will be as it is
});
```